# Unable to get simple string to print correctly

Tags: python, pycharm

We have an assignment to create a code where there is user input and it should print out like this.

What is your name? **Amanda**
How old are you? **2005**

Hello **Amanda**! You were born in **2005**.

**My Code:**

```
user_name = input('What is your name?')
user_age = int(input('How old are you?'))
birth_year = (2021 - user_age)
print()
print('Hello', user_name, '!', 'You were born in', birth_year, '.')
```

**My Output:**
What is your name?**'nikki'**
How old are you?**'27'**
()
('Hello', 'nikki', '!', 'You were born in', 1994, '.')

Process finished with exit code 0

I can't figure out how to get the parentheses to not go around the output print string. I am doing everything we were taught so super confused. I also have to enter the input in '' or else it won't work.I've tried separating the string into two separate print strings. That didn't work. Also tried changing the commas to + which was even more of an error.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I don't get `()` in my output with your code.

Comment: Odd, it works for me, no parentheses printed.

Comment: What strange version of Python are you running? Here both Python 2 (obsolete, don't use) and Python 3 (precisely 3.9.7 on Fedora Linux 34) give what you expect.

Comment: You're using Python 2 (which is quite old).  Is that on purpose?

Comment: No I am just learning Python and had no idea I was even using it. First class ever in coding so doing my best to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using Python 2.x by accident instead of Python 3.x.

In Python 2, `print` is a keyword instead of function, so `print ()` prints an empty tuple.

Also in Python 2 `input()` evaluates user's input as a Python expression. To read a string, you had to use `raw_input()`. In Python 3 `input()` does what `raw_input()` did.

Comment: Python 2 works fine.

Comment: The example given is clearly intended for Python 3 - why would you ever write int(input()) in Python 2.

Comment: figured out how to change it to Python 3 and it works perfect now, thank you so much for the help!